# error while using the EXCEPT identifier in sql query

Tags: sql, forms, except

i have a user table with one attribute as habits that has valus like shopping,sports etc. Now when i log in to my application i get the username from the FORM tag and this is used in javascript for further use. I need a query that displays all the user table contents where habits=shopping but it shouldnt display the details of the currently logged in user. The query i used for this is,
**select * from user where habits='shopping' except select * from user where username='niranjan';**

But this line is generating an error stating that the EXCEPT identifier is not a valid input at this point.
pls correct my error or provide an alternative code for my issue.

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? Not all of them support `EXCEPT`, but if you post the structure of the `user` table we can assist in correcting the query without it (possibly as simple as `SELECT * FROM user WHERE habits='shopping' AND username <> 'niranjan'`)

Comment: thanks a lot @micheal berkowski !!! it actually worked. I used the ' <> ' symbol that helped me solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user where habits='shopping' and username!='niranjan';
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for except here. Just add a condition to your where caluse:

```
And username <> 'niranjan'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that `user` is a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) for SQL Server.  I would suggest that you rename the table to `users` to get around this problem.

In the meantime, you can use square braces for the query:

```
select * from [user] where habits = 'shopping'
except
select * from [user] where username = 'niranjan';
```

However, it is bad form to use reserved words for table and column names.

Comment: Though I agree that using reserved words is a bad habit, why keep the except when it can clearly be replaced with adding a condition to the first select statment? Am I missing something here or are you?

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . I think you are right, because of the  `select *`.  There are cases where the `select` could have a subset of columns, and the two versions would not be equivalent.